# How can i get all background running process list?

Tags: java, android

How can i get all background running process list that are running background in my android like services, tasks or any other threads related to all android all including internal(Android self apps) external(Installed Apps).

Answer (score 1):

With this code You can get currently running services.

```
ActivityManager localActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List RunningServiceInfoservices = localActivityManager.getRunningServices(100);
```

Refer this [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html)

Comment: This is an old thread and i've been searching for this question.  It seems like all the answers are from 4 years ago and every working method has been deprecated.  Is there any new solution for this?

Comment: With this line you will get only services, that were started by your package.